# How can you add functionality to toolbars within fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I understand similar questions have previously been asked, but for some reason despite having tried multiple solutions, I am not able to get this to work.

Basically I have created a toolbar in my fragments XML file and put all its components into the items menu file (bottom_navigation_menu). However when I click on the items in the menu, they are getting no response. I tried adding a log.d, to see if the setnavigationonclick function is being called and it isn't. I have attached my code below.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class pneumothorax_fr_flashcard_view extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "flashcard view";
    private pneumothorax_layout_flashcard_view customView;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pneumothorax_flashcard_view,container,false);
        customView = (pneumothorax_layout_flashcard_view) view.findViewById(R.id.flashcardView);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarBot);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();


        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                customView.swapColor();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }



}
```

Here is the XML, in this file I have both a toolbar and a custom view which has a green box, the colour of that box is meant to change when onclick is performed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbarBot"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content">
       <com.example.spidermed.pneumothorax_layout_flashcard_view
           android:id="@+id/flashcardView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`setOnMenuItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar?hl=en#setOnMenuItemClickListener(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener)) to handle menu items. `setNavigationOnClickListener` is only for the navigation button on the left hand side (which only displays if you call [`setNavigationIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar?hl=en#setNavigationIcon(int)) to set an icon for it).

Comment: thank you, I guess I just had a bit of a brain freeze, I also realised that my swap colour method doesn't work, but at least you solved my issue thanks. I have changed my code accordingly to demonstrate the solution

Answer (score 0):

User IanHanniballake posted the correct answer, here is my updated code

```
public class pneumothorax_fr_flashcard_view extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "flashcard view";
    private pneumothorax_layout_flashcard_view customView;




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pneumothorax_flashcard_view,container,false);
        customView = (pneumothorax_layout_flashcard_view) view.findViewById(R.id.flashcardView);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarBot);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.forwardButton:
                        customView.swapColor();
                        Log.d(TAG,"this is working");
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

}
```